# How to pin a common column on all the sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am building a google sheet spanning multiple sheets. I have an index page with hyperlinks to few select sheets for convenience.
I'm looking to pin this column to show up on all the sheets.

Most suggestions I found online is about copying over the column from index page to all sheets, which I find hard to maintain and scale.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion:

Perhaps you can [add this sample bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#google_sheets) below to your spreadsheet file then save & run it from the editor:

> To create a bound script in Google Sheets, open your spreadsheet and click **Extensions or Tools > Apps Script or Script Editor**

```
function onEdit() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var indexPage = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet").getRange("A:A");
 var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  sheets.forEach(cursheet => {
    indexPage.copyTo(ss.getSheetByName(cursheet.getName()).getRange("A:A")); //Copies index on every sheets' column A
    ss.getSheetByName(cursheet.getName()).setFrozenColumns(1); //// Freezes the first column on every sheet
  });
}
```

> This script will also automatically run every time you edit (that means every time you press `Enter` key after editing/adding a new cell value) your spreadsheet file as it was configured with `onEdit` trigger

### Sample Result

After saving & running the script from the Apps Script editor:

> `Sheet`:

[image]

> `Wish List`

[image]

> `Laptops`

[image]

> `Apparel`

[image]

### Reference:

[Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

[Apps Script: setFrozenColumns(columns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setfrozencolumnscolumns)

Comment: @Anil I hope this helps, just feel free to let me know if ever I have misunderstood your goal.

Comment: @Anil You're very welcome. If we answered your question, you may want to click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved & they'll easily see this post on their searches.

Comment: Yes, this is the exact functionality Im looking for, but also wondering if can be done without external scripts.

Comment: @Anil I did a bit of research and it looks like this can only be achieved via Apps Script as there's no dedicated option on Google Sheet settings that will make a pinned/frozen column visible across every sheet tabs on a spreadsheet file unfortunately. The closest option is this button [here](https://imgur.com/a/BPfnvoD)

Comment: No worries. This might be why they had Apps script to allow advanced usecases. I'm gonna try this out!